# Routing to a URL behaves differently in config

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am attempting to get familiar with spring-cloud-gateway and I am having a problem configuring routes in YAML. I am attempting to do a simple redirect based on path to httpbin.org. This works fine when I do this in code but when I am attempting this in YAML config I get a 404.
YAML:

```
  -  id: demo
         uri: http://httpbin.org
         predicates:
         - Path=/demo
```

When I attempt this route, it looks like the route is getting matched- I dont see a 404 for the route itself. What I get in the response is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try
    again.</p>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There's no path /demo on httpbin

Comment: Ugh! Sorry, I was so sure it was something in my yaml I did not realize I had not changed my path predicate.